# How to stop a sound that is playing in Python?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

So I have code that looks like this:

```
    import winsound
    from msvcrt import getch

    sound_path = "Path to sound"

    while True:
        key= ord(getch())
        if key == 27:
            break
        if key == 113: #theq key
            winsound.PlaySound(sound_path, winsound.SND_FILENAME)
```

So right now if I press the 'q' key, it plays the corresponding sound like it should. However if I keep pressing the 'q' key before the current sound is done playing, it will play after the current sound is finished. How would I have it so upon pressing the 'q' button, it would stop the current noise and play the next one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit:**
Having looked further into it (Win7, Python3.6.1), *Eswcvlads* answer is the way to go. When using the `winsound.SND_ASYNC` flag, you can immediately play another sound and the currently playing sound stops.

```
winsound.PlaySound(r'D:\seven_11.wav', winsound.SND_ASYNC)
```

*-> plays seven_11*

```
winsound.PlaySound(r'D:\seven_12.wav', winsound.SND_ASYNC)
```

*-> seven_11 stops and seven_12 starts playing*

However, to stop all playback, my original approach is still valid:

```
winsound.PlaySound(None, winsound.SND_PURGE)
```

---

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/winsound.html#winsound.PlaySound):

> `winsound.PlaySound(sound, flags)` ... If the sound parameter is `None`, any currently playing waveform sound is stopped.

So including that before calling PlaySound for the next one should stop the playback before starting the next.

Comment: Tried `winsound.Playsoud(None, winsound.SND_FILENAME)` like you said, but the program crashes when I run it like that. Runs fine without that line.

Comment: @JoshuaKim it what manner does it crash? `Playsoud` is not the same as `PlaySound`.

Comment: Perfect, using winsound.SND_ASYNC did the job. Thank you for such a detailed & useful answer.

Answer (score 5):

Judging by the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/winsound.html#winsound.PlaySound), by default, PlaySound is synchronous, so it returns only after the sound has been fully played. So the script processes the next key only when the sound ended. To make it async use the `winsound.SND_ASYNC` flag like this:

```
winsound.PlaySound(sound_path, winsound.SND_FILENAME | winsound.SND_ASYNC)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
if key == 113: #theq key
        winsound.Playsound(None, windsound.SND_FILENAME)
        winsound.PlaySound(sound_path, winsound.SND_FILENAME)
```

If the sound parameter is None, any currently playing waveform sound is stopped. So do that before every sound file played.