# how to kill winsound task after an if condition

Tags: python, python-multithreading, alarm, winsound

I have a code that will play an alarm then when I press h it should stop working here's the code:

```
import winsound
from threading import Thread
import keyboard
import sys


alarm_flag = True


def alarm():
    global alarm_flag
    while alarm_flag:
        winsound.PlaySound("C:\\windows\\media\\Alarm01.wav", winsound.SND_FILENAME)
        

def stop_alarm():
    global alarm_flag
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed("h"):
            alarm_flag = False

alarm_thread = Thread(target=alarm)
stop_alarm_thread = Thread(target=stop_alarm)

alarm_thread.start()
stop_alarm_thread.start()
```

when I press "h" it will wait for the winsound to end (it's a 5 second alarm) and then exits the program I want it to kill everything when I press "h" so the winsound will stop at the middle, first or end no matter what I also tried with `sys.exit()` but it's not working

Comment: [windows - How to stop a sound that is playing in Python? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43758189/how-to-stop-a-sound-that-is-playing-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it with pygame instead of winsound (thanks to chatGPT) here's how :

```
    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load("C:\\windows\\media\\Alarm01.wav")
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)  # -1 for looping
```

and the whole code will look like this :

```
import pygame
from threading import Thread
import keyboard
import sys
import time

alarm_flag = True


def alarm():
    global alarm_flag
    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load("C:\\windows\\media\\Alarm01.wav")
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)  # -1 for looping

    while alarm_flag:
        time.sleep(1)


def stop_alarm():
    global alarm_flag
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed("Esc"):
            alarm_flag = False
            pygame.mixer.music.stop()
            sys.exit()


alarm_thread = Thread(target=alarm)
stop_alarm_thread = Thread(target=stop_alarm)

alarm_thread.start()
stop_alarm_thread.start()
```